# Discord.py - How can i send a private message only for online/dnd/idle members, not for at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My code is right there:

```py
x = ctx.guild.members == online
s = 0
for member in x:
    try:
        await member.send(embed=embed1)
        await member.send('|| https://discord.gg/y7EEXwU ||')
        print(f'{member.name} | {s}')
        s += 1
    except:
        pass
```

Can someone help me?
Detail: the code is well summarized to fit properly to the post template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `discord.Status` for filtration members. [Link for discord.Status docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Status) Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    members = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID).members # all members
    # members with status online
    online_members = [member for member in members if member.status == discord.Status.online] 
    for member in online_members:
        try:
            await member.send("Hello")
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: I really tried to use discord.Status, but it didn't work, when I used it, I said no Status was not set... I didn't quite understand why.

Comment: Could you send your code in your post? I want to understand your problem.

Comment: So, I tried according to your tips just above, using Code, I did it, but now I would like to send it to all members with the exception of Offlines.
I tried the following code:

Comment: You can use: `members_without_offline = [member for member in members if member.status != discord.Status.offline]`

Comment: So then, the bot will send a private message for everyone that isn't in the Offline Status ?

Comment: Yes only for members without the offline status

Comment: Do you need to send one message with embed and one message with link next? Or link and embed it's one message?

Comment: There is an embed, which in this case is embed1, which already contains a message, the link I want to send outside embed1, but in the same message that the bot will send in `await member.send`.
You see?

Comment: Try this: `await member.send(embed=your_embed, content='some_string')`. You send one message with embed and some text in content.

Comment: Ok, i will try it

Comment: Yeah, i got it, but the link was first that embed, is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I think not, this is a feature of the message

Comment: Oh, since it is so then, fine.
I thank you a thousand times for your help, friend, really.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark my answer as solution if it's helped you?

Comment: Of Course, friend !